# How to show search results in Outlook search

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am working on addin to Outlook 2013. I added custom field to MailItem and used AdvancedSearch to find item. The last missing part is showing the results.

How can I show results of custom search in search results?

```
    private void Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(Outlook.Search SearchObject)
    {
        string dx = SearchObject.Tag;
        int x = SearchObject.Results.Count;
        //What next?
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Object selObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
        Outlook.MailItem mail = selObject as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (mail != null)
        {
            Outlook.UserProperties mailUserProperties = null;
            Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = null;
            mailUserProperties = mail.UserProperties;
            foreach (var i in mailUserProperties)
            {
                var xx = i;
            }
            mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties.Add("TestUserProperty", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true);
            mailUserProperty.Value = "Eugene Astafiev";
            mail.Save();
        }

        string str = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/TestUserProperty LIKE '%ugene%'";
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AdvancedSearch("Inbox", str, false, "TestUserProperty");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display the results of Application.AdvancedSearch.  To show search results in the UI you will have to use Explorer.Search, which is effectively just automating the user performing the search in the UI.  However, you will not get the results back in code to work with.  See here for an overview of your options:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869846.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can save results to a search folder and then display it to a user. The [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868367.aspx) method of the Search class saves the search results to a Search Folder. Note, the `Save` method displays an error if a Search Folder with the same name already exists.

```
        Outlook.Results advancedSearchResults = advancedSearch.Results;
        if (advancedSearchResults.Count > 0)
        {
            if (HostMajorVersion > 10)
            {
                object folder = advancedSearch.GetType().InvokeMember("Save", 
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public,
                                   null, advancedSearch, 
                                   new object[] { advancedSearchTag });

            }
            else
            {
                strBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                strBuilder.AppendLine("Number of items found: " +
                          advancedSearchResults.Count.ToString());                            
                for (int i = 1; i < = advancedSearchResults.Count; i++)
                {                                
                    resultItem = advancedSearchResults[i] 
                                      as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (resultItem != null)
                    {
                        strBuilder.Append("#" + i.ToString());
                        strBuilder.Append(" Subject: " + resultItem.Subject);
                        strBuilder.Append(" \t To: " + resultItem.To);
                        strBuilder.AppendLine(" \t Importance: " + 
                                           resultItem.Importance.ToString());
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem);
                    }
                }
                if (strBuilder.Length > 0)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());   
                else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                                            "There are no Mail items found.");
             }
        }
        else
        {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There are no items found.");
        }
```

You may find the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article helpful.